# Auto-formatting Existing Word 2013 Docs with Headings based on characters

Tags: formatting, microsoft-word-2013, styles

I have 150 Word 2013 Docs that are laid out in the same, uniform way. (note: the # of articles in each document varies).
Each document has a summary and some articles.

Question: Is there a way to get Word to auto-detect this format and assign Headings based on this format? I'd like every line that begins with a single (*) to be autoformatted as Heading 1 and every line that begins with 2 asterisks (**) to be autoformatted as Heading 2. To be more clear, I'd like 'SUMMARY' and 'ARTICLES' to be formatted as Heading 1, and each 'Article' to be formatted as Heading 2. Thanks for your help in advance.

Below, is an example of what the formatting currently looks like:

*SUMMARY (would like this be Heading 1)

```
The Summary text is here
```

*ARTICLES (would like this be Heading 1)

**Article Title (would like this be Heading 2)

```
The article text is here
```

**Article Title (would like this be Heading 2)

```
The article text is here
```

**Article Title (would like this be Heading 2)

```
The article text is here
```

**Article Title (would like this be Heading 2)

```
The article text is here
```